# Turning one array into two hashes

Tags: ruby

I want to split:

```
array = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]
```

into two hashes like this:

```
hash1 = {"a" => "b", "d" => "e", "g" => "h"}
hash2 = {"a" => "c", "d" => "f", "g" => "i"}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Always show your code, what you did before you ask for help

Comment: Thanks for the greenie, but I would encourage you to wait longer before awarding the checkmark to anyone. A quick selection may discourage other answers and imo is a little discourteous to others still working on answers. The point is, there's no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hours--some much longer--before selecting an answer. If you wish, you can retract your selection and reconsider later.

Comment: Got it. Will do next time.
I figure I didn't want to waste people's time if I got the answer I was looking for. But if you think it would be good for others to work on it, I can wait. :) 
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]

hash1 = array.map { |f,m,_| [f,m] }.to_h
  #=> {"a"=>"b", "d"=>"e", "g"=>"h"}
hash2 = array.map { |f,_,l| [f,l] }.to_h
  #=> {"a"=>"c", "d"=>"f", "g"=>"i"}
```

or

```
def doit(arr, i1, i2)
  arr.map { |a| [a[i1], a[i2]] }.to_h
end

hash1 = doit(array, 0, 1)
  #=> {"a"=>"b", "d"=>"e", "g"=>"h"}
hash2 = doit(array, 0, 2)
  #=> {"a"=>"c", "d"=>"f", "g"=>"i"}
```

Comment: A bit of symmetry would be nice `hash1 = array.map { |f,m,_| [f,m] }.to_h`.

Comment: @Sagar, I agree. Made the change. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `each` loop would work:

```
array = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]

hash1 = {}
hash2 = {}

array.each do |k, v1, v2|
  hash1[k] = v1
  hash2[k] = v2
end

hash1 #=> {"a"=>"b", "d"=>"e", "g"=>"h"}
hash2 #=> {"a"=>"c", "d"=>"f", "g"=>"i"}
```

Comment: Great answer. Just wondering whether it is reasonable to refer to the `each` method as a _loop_?

Comment: @SagarPandya if `array.each { ... }` is not a _loop_, then what is it?

Comment: Good point. Wikipedia: _"A loop is a sequence of statements which is specified once but which may be carried out several times in succession"_. So of course `each` is that. Not sure why that confused me. Perhaps I'm only use to referring to `while`, `for` and `until` etc as loops.

Answer (score 1):

Just two more ways, though the first one destructs your array in the process.

Build `hash2` first by popping so `hash1` becomes trivial:

```
hash2 = array.map { |a| [a[0], a.pop] }.to_h
hash1 = array.to_h
```

First separate key and values columns, then zip them back together:

```
k, *v = array.transpose
hash1, hash2 = v.map { |v| k.zip(v).to_h }
```

(Thanks to Sagar Pandya for that, I had used `k, *v = array.shift.zip(*array)` before.)

Comment: Use `k, *v = array.transpose` (non-destructive too).

Comment: @SagarPandya Ah, right. I've even used `transpose` before, but apparently forgot. I guess Python's `zip` is too ingrained in my brain.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]
hashes = {}
array.each do |subarray|
  subarray[1..-1].each_with_index do |item, index|
    hashes[index] ||= {}
    hashes[index][subarray.first] = item
  end
end

puts hashes.values
```

Comment: This answer does not provide an explanation. Please explain your answers.